# The (easy to check?) continuity of an inclusion between Lebesgue-Bochner spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Let $A$, $B$ and $X$ be Banach spaces such that

- $A$ and $B$ are reflexive;
- $A\subset X$ with a compact injection;
- $X\subset B$ with a continuous injection.

For $1<a,b<\infty$, set
$$W:=\{v\;|\;v\in L^a(0,T;A),\; v'\in L^b(0,T;B)\},$$

where $v'$ is the derivative of $v$ in the distributional sense.

[Here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=CKYJBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA184&lpg=PA184&dq=%22and%20the%20continuity%20of%20the%20injection%20is%20very%20easy%20to%20check%22&source=bl&ots=0puNUWb3Pg&sig=QxBgOh7JixhyfTOLD8afru5C4EI&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAWoVChMIiey54bL1yAIVBseQCh0lugrU#v=onepage&q=%22and%20the%20continuity%20of%20the%20injection%20is%20very%20easy%20to%20check%22&f=false) (in the middle of the proof of the Aubin-Lions Lemma) the author uses the follwing fact:

> $W\subset C([0,T];B)$ with a continuous injection.

To justify, he says: *The inclusion results from Lemma 1.1, and **the continuity of the injection is very easy to check.***

The part of the inclusion is ok (because form the Lemma 1.1 we conclude that if $v\in L^1(0,T; A)$ and $v'\in L^1(0,T; B)$, then $v$ is a. e. equal to a continuous function).

Could someone explain me the "very easy" part? To get the inclusion, it is enough to assume $A\subset B$ with continuous injection. To get (in a easy way) the continuity, should we exploit the compactness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From formula (1.15) in Lemma 1.1, you have
$$v(t) = v_0 + \int_0^t v'(s) \, \mathrm{d}s.$$
Hence,
$$\|v(t)\|_B \le \|v_0\|_B + \| v' \|_{L^1(0,T;B)}.$$
Similarly, you can estimate $\|v_0\|_B$ by using $\|v\|_{L^1(0,T;B)}$.

In fact (by using a slightly different proof), one even has
$$\|v\|_{L^\infty(0,T;B)} \le T^{-1} \, \|v\|_{L^1(0,T;B)} + \|v'\|_{L^1(0,T;B)}$$
for all $v \in W^{1,1}(0,T;B)$.

Comment: I didn't get the estimate $\|v_0\|_B\leq \|v\|_{L^1(0,T;B)}$. Could you give some more details?

Comment: You do not have $\|u_0\|B \le \|v\|_{L^1(0,T;B)}$, but from $v_0 = v(t) - \int_0^t v' \, \mathrm{d}s$ you get $\|v_0\|_B \le \|v(t)\|_B + \|v'\|_{L^1(0,T;B)}$. Hence, $T \, \|v_0\|_B \le \|v\|_{L^1(0,T;B)} + T \, \|v'\|_{L^1(0,T;B)}$.